# Can I get this sales comparison into a single column?

Tags: sql, case-when

Here is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES (
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER,
    price DECIMAL(2,2)
);

INSERT INTO SALES VALUES
    ("2017-02-08 13:38:02", "apple", 6, 4.38),
    ("2017-02-08 13:38:02", "banana", 10, 3.50),
    ("2017-02-08 13:38:02", "orange", 8, 2.98),
    ("2017-02-08 09:21:52", "banana", 6, 2.67),
    ("2017-02-08 09:21:52", "pear", 3, 2.00),
    ("2017-02-07 15:21:32", "apple", 6, 4.38),
    ("2017-02-07 15:21:32", "banana", 6, 2.67),
    ("2017-02-07 11:03:16", "orange", 8, 2.98),
    ("2017-02-07 11:03:16", "banana", 4, 1.17);
```

I'd like to get items that sold today but not yesterday.

I can get them in 2 columns using:

```
select
    name,
    SUM(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d', sales_ts) = '2017-02-08' then quantity  else 0 end) as today,
    SUM(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d', sales_ts) = '2017-02-07' then quantity  else 0 end) as yday
from sales
group by name
having yday = 0
```

Result:

```
| name | today | yday
---------------------
| pear |   3   |  0
```

But how could I get just 2 columns, 1 for name and 1 called "sold_today_but_not_yday" with a True/False value? Is that possible? (preferably without using subqueries).

Comment: Your code appears to be SQLite.  SQLite doesn't have a boolean column.  Does an integer with 0/1 satisfy your need?

Comment: Yep, 0 and 1 are fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case`:

```
select name,
       (case when SUM(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d', sales_ts) = '2017-02-08' then quantity  else 0 end) > 0 and
                  SUM(case when strftime('%Y-%m-%d', sales_ts) = '2017-02-07' then quantity  else 0 end) = 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as isTodayNotYesterday
from sales
group by name;
```